# How can I handle multiple AJAX results in a userscript?

Tags: javascript, loops, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm currently developing a Greasemonkey script to translate `<textarea>` fields in an Intranet app, using Google Translation API.

But some texts are way too large to be translated with only one request. I get this error when trying :

> Request entity too large

Anyway, I found a way to cut the texts in fragments, and send them in separate requests. Where it gets tricky, is how I should replace those fragments in their original textareas, and especially at the right place.

After trying several methods without any success, I inserted placeholders in the textarea, corresponding to the fragments of text that have to be translated :

```
{1}
{2}
...
```

But now in the success callback of my XHR, I have to replace the placeholder with the translated text. The thing is, my XHR is inside a `for` loop, iterating over my table containing the fragments of original text, and when the requests finish, the loop is long finished and I don't know how to get where to put the translation.

Here's the code :

```
//Array text[] contains the fragments of original text
var translated_text = [];
var l = text.length;
for(var i = 0; i < l; i++)
{
var fullurl = apiurl+encodeURIComponent(text[i]);
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: 'GET',
    url: fullurl,
    headers:
    {
        'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible) Greasemonkey',
        'Accept': 'application/atom+xml,application/xml,text/xml',
    },
    onload: function(responseDetails)
    {
        var destination = "{"+i+"}";
        if(responseDetails.status == 200)
        {
            var data = $.parseJSON(responseDetails.responseText);
            translated_text[i] = data.responseData.translatedText.replace(/&quot;/g,"\"").replace(/&#39;/g,"\"").replace(/&gt;/g,">");
            textarea.text(textarea.text().replace("{"+i+"}",translated_text[i]));
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Request Failed : '+responseDetails.status+"\nError : "+responseDetails.statusText);
        }
    }
});
}
```

PS : I cannot use jQuery's AJAX methods, because this is a Cross Domain request, so the new `$.when` functionality cannot be used here (sadly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**  With newer versions of Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey, you can now **pass [a `context`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest#Arguments):**

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
   method:   'GET',
   url:      fullurl,
   context:  i,
   headers:  {
               'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible) Greasemonkey',
               'Accept': 'application/atom+xml,application/xml,text/xml',
             },
   onload:   function (responseDetails) {
                var destination = "{" + responseDetails.context + "}";  // context is `i`
                if (responseDetails.status == 200) {
                   var data           = $.parseJSON (responseDetails.responseText);
                   translated_text[i] = data.responseData.translatedText.replace (/&quot;/g,"\"")
                                      .replace (/&#39;/g,"\"").replace (/&gt;/g,">")
                                      ;
                   textarea.text (textarea.text ().replace ("{"+i+"}",translated_text[i]) );
                }
                else {
                   alert (
                      'Request Failed : '+responseDetails.status+"\nError : "
                      + responseDetails.statusText
                   );
                }
             }
} );
```

---

For other/older platforms, to use the value of `i`, you need to **wrap it in a [JavaScript closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/).**   One way to do do that is:

```
( function (i)  {
   GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
      method:   'GET',
      url:      fullurl,
      headers:  {
                  'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible) Greasemonkey',
                  'Accept': 'application/atom+xml,application/xml,text/xml',
                },
      onload:   function (responseDetails) {
                   var destination = "{"+i+"}";
                   if (responseDetails.status == 200) {
                      var data           = $.parseJSON (responseDetails.responseText);
                      translated_text[i] = data.responseData.translatedText.replace (/&quot;/g,"\"")
                                         .replace (/&#39;/g,"\"").replace (/&gt;/g,">")
                                         ;
                      textarea.text (textarea.text ().replace ("{"+i+"}",translated_text[i]) );
                   }
                   else {
                      alert (
                         'Request Failed : '+responseDetails.status+"\nError : "
                         + responseDetails.statusText
                      );
                   }
                }
   } );
} ) (i);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it you can use jQuery to do cross domain requests like this...

```
function pass_ajax(url,text_to_translate){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url,
      crossDomain: true,
      data: text_to_translate,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        req = data; //here you can sanitize the data before concatenating
      },
      complete: function(xhr,textStatus){
        translated_text += req;
      }
    });
```

The 'crossDomain: true' property is new to jQuery 1.5. Also, I think you could make use of success and complete and just concatenate the text as it returns, assigning it to a variable with outer scope.

Comment: It works perfectly with jQuery 1.5.1, except for the ajax/cross-domain part