# Synchronous GM_xmlhttpRequest acting asynchronously?

Tags: synchronization, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get a `GM_xmlhttpRequest` call to behave synchronously, but I can't get it to work like I expect:

```
function myFunction (arg) {
    var a;

    GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
        method:         "GET",
        url:            "http://example.com/sample/url",
        synchronous:    true,

        onload: function (details) {
            a = details.responseText;
        }
    } );

    return a;
}
b = myFunction ();
alert (b);
```

I never get anything back for `b` here; it's undefined.  Is there some step that I'm missing here?
I'm using v0.9.13 of Greasemonkey, and v9.0.1 of Firefox.

Comment: Yeah... I had to restructure my code due to this "bug"

Comment: Don't use synchronous requests.  Use an asynchronous approach as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32338061/), or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5192249/331508), etc.

Answer (score 6):

Just stumbled upon this topic in Google.

Synchronous GM_xmlhttpRequest RETURN the result instead of executing it in the onload-callback.

So this would be right:

```
var details = GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method:"GET",
  url:"http://site.com/sample/url",
  synchronous: true
});
a = details.responseText;
```

You create the var "a" in the beginning, never fill it and return it. Therefore, it is undefined.